# Loading recyclerview with Images and Video

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build an app that shows feeds of twitter,Facebook and Instagram. I've three fragments in total for each of the social media platform and each fragment contains Recyclerview. I am facing problem of efficiently loading media. I'm using Picasso for loading images and have handled video using MediaPlayer. Since, the feeds contain video as well as images, I've both ImageView and SurfaceView (*VideoView doesn't fill video to size of the view*)                   in my layout file and have hidden either ImageView or SurfaceView depending on the data. 
I've also built a Custom SurfaceView which handles video and image but it is bit laggy. Is there any better way to handle Images and video in a single view?

Any help or improvement will help a lot. Thank you

Here is my layout file for twitter list item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom_text="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/retweet_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:contentDescription="@string/none"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_retweet" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/retweet_user_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitter_profilePicture"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/none"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <MerchantApp.Android.Controls.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    custom_text:customTypeface="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" />


                <MerchantApp.Android.Controls.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    custom_text:customTypeface="Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twitter_follow_follower_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followers_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/following_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <MerchantApp.Android.Controls.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLength="160"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/text"
                custom_text:customTypeface="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/animated_loading" />

            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1.0">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_reply"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter_reply" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_retweeted_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_retweeted_image"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter_retweet" />

                    <MerchantApp.Android.Controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_retweeted_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:text="@string/text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        custom_text:customTypeface="Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_favorite_layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_favorite_image"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter_favorite" />

                    <MerchantApp.Android.Controls.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/twitter_feed_favorite_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:text="@string/text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        custom_text:customTypeface="Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/feed_follow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/none"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter_feed_follow" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I build a MediaPlaceholder, that rendered videoview/imageview on run time instead of hiding it.
 Depending on the data(i.e Image/URL/Video) appropriate methods are called.   eg: makeSingleImageLoader()/ makeUrlLoader(), makeVideoView()..
It isn't efficient solution but this kind of worked for me.

MediaPlaceHolder

```
public class MediaPlaceholder : LinearLayout
{
    Context mContext;
    PoppingImageView imageView;
    UrlLoader urlLoader;
    MultiImageView multiImageView;
    BufferingSurfaceView bufferingSurfaceView;


    public MediaPlaceholder(Context context) : base(context) {
        init(context);
    }

    public MediaPlaceholder(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) {
        init(context);
    }

    public MediaPlaceholder(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init(context);
    }

    void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    void prepareView() {
        this.RemoveAllViews ();
        }


    public void makeUrlLoaderView(String url) {
        prepareView();
        if (urlLoader == null) {
            urlLoader = new UrlLoader(mContext);
        }
        urlLoader.loadPreview(url);
        AddView(urlLoader, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
    }

  //So if it is ImageView, this method is called and another custom view is rendered in the placeholder,   
  //PoppingImageView in this case and videoView in case of video
    public void makeSingleImageView(IMedia imageUrl) {
        prepareView();
        if (imageView == null) {
            imageView = new PoppingImageView(mContext);
        }
        imageView.setDataresources(imageUrl, 0).enableDialogPopup(true);
        AddView(imageView, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
    }

    public void makeVideoView(String videoUrl, int position) {
        prepareView();
        if (bufferingSurfaceView == null) {
            bufferingSurfaceView = new BufferingSurfaceView(mContext);
        }
        bufferingSurfaceView.setMediaSource(videoUrl,position);
        AddView(bufferingSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
    }
}
```